# Event Bubbling or Looping Callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am having trouble with JQuery / javascript / Knockout.js

The events are looping incrementally every time they are called.

Like for example, a click event with alert.

If I click once, it will alert once.

BUT, if I click the second time, it will alert twice.

That goes on the third time and so on, It loops by the number of times it was called.

I am quite risking myself here because I cannot paste the codes unless I give you the whole program which is not possible because this is an incomplete company project.

So I am very sorry if I don't have any codes to provide. I just need ideas / answers / possible solutions.

What do you call this problems? Is it Event Bubbling?

So my main question is, is it possible to stop all the events after calling it once? I have no loop statements whatsoever, all I have is some functions and an `.on('click'...` events

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my question.

Since the .on events are stacking every time it's clicked, and once you clicked it twice, the events will also fire twice, then I had to insert .off() before .on('click', functionName);

That makes it like this:

`$('testBtn').off().on('click', functionName);`

That should clear up all the event stacking.

Answer (score 0):

One common situation when binding click events is to have a common handler being used in both parent and child elements.

Example:

```
<div id="parent" data-bind="click: doSomething">
    <a data-bind="click: doSomething">Clickable</a>
</div>
```

When the child is clicked its handler, **doSomething**, will be triggered once, and then the parent click handler, that again calls **doSomething**, will be also triggered.

To prevent event propagation in scenarios like this you can set the extra **clickBubble** binding to false in the inner element.

Example:

```
<div id="parent" data-bind="click: doSomething">
    <a data-bind="click: doSomething, clickBubble: false">Clickable</a>
</div>
```

More about all the details of the click binding [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).